Lost on Git Clone "--recursive" Option
We have cloned a Git repository but forgot to use the --recursive option.
git clone --recursive git@example.net:repository/pathname
          ~~~~~~~~~~~

How can we do it afterwards within the work-tree locally at ./pathname in the projects shell?
Reason is that we first cloned the repository that was already available but only later found out about the contribution guidelines that show the git-clone command with the --recursive option, but now the repository is already cloned.
Our local file system comes close to recursive if we create an endless loop with relative symbolic links.
We know that Git has support for symbolic links and therefore we checked the cloned repository but found none in there.
Therefore we guess, that the --recursive option was not even necessary in the first place, but regardless, if that actually is a Git clone option, we are confident it must be possible to apply it later on.
But how?

The --recursive option for git-clone(1) is undocumented in the release notes (as we were later able to learn about by the help of @phd).
We have had the educated guess that it is related to submodules, not symbolically linking in the file system, as there is an --recurse-submodules option.
Its description then suggests to us; the command to run is:
git submodule update --init --recursive :/

If we try it out, we may then learn that there are not even Git submodules in the cloned repository.
Therefore we conclude in good faith that the contribution guidelines in that project are showing the known, just more verbose, way to clone the Git repository.

"git clone" learned --recursive option in release 1.6.5. I don't remember when it was renamed to --recurse-submodules but there is the following note in the release notes for version 2.22.0: "disambiguate between --recursive and --recurse-submodules, which is bad because these two are synonyms."

@phd: We stand corrected, thank you very, very much for your comment.
